# ¿por que si un elemento tiene el mismo alto que ancho no se ve como cuadrado? ¿y como corregir esto con java script?

Tags: javascript

Tengo 4 cuadrados alineados en mi pagina. Cada uno tiene una propiedad de 25% de ancho. De modo que entre todos cubren el 100% del ancho de la pantalla. Esto es diseño liquido para que sin importar el ancho de la pantalla con el que se visualice los cuadrados siempre llenen todo el espacio. El problema que tengo es EL ALTO. No puedo ponerle porcentajes de alto porque el contenedor no tiene una altura fija, sino que cambia segun el contenido. No le puedo poner tampoco pixeles de alto, porque por ejemplo si le pongo 250px de alto x 25% de ancho, en una laptop de 1366 x 760 se veria bien, PERO, cuando se use una computadora de 1600 x 1080, el cuadrado perfecto se veria rectangulo, ya que el ancho se expandiria mas hasta cubrir todo pero el alto seria el mismo de siempre. ¿se entiende? Lo que quiero es un cuadrado perfecto que se vea igual en todos los tamaños de pantalla. Para esto se me ocurrio usar java script, el siguiente codigo:

```
s2d = $( 'div' ).outerWidth(  ); //recojo el ancho del elemento
$( 'div' ).css( 'height', s2d ); //le pongo a mi elemento de ALTO el mismo ancho recogido, para que sea un cuadrado perfecto
```

Pero NO FUNCIONA T_T.. O sea el codigo si, pero se ve rectangular mi intento de cuadrado. Y esto en el mundo fisico seria imposible, es decir deberia salirme un cuadrado perfecto. Quisiera dos cosas: Primero que por favor alguien me explique por que se ve un rectangulo y no un cuadrado, y segundo ¿como lo soluciono, como obtengo un cuadrado perfecto?... ¿hay un medida estandarizada para obtener un cuadrado? Esta claro que tendria que restarle un poco a mi alto para que se un cuadrado perfecto, pero mi temor es que en unas computadoras la medida de 100x100 se vea como rectangulo y en otras se vea como cuadrado..eso seria un problema

Comment: Tiene que ser en Javascript? Eso que necesitas puede hacerse perfectamente con CSS, revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21738815/7023800) http://jsfiddle.net/tu8spbf0/1/

Comment: prueba cambiando el min-height en lugar del height y me cuentas!